# django - invalid syntax (urls.py, line 7)

Tags: django

I'm doing a slight variation on my urls.py from the tutorial where I have the following -

mysite/urls.py -

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^TidalDEV/', include('TidalDEV.urls')),
)
```

TidalDEV/urls.py -

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from TidalDEV import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.tesxml, name='tesxml'),
)
```

And this is the view in views.py -

```
def tesxml(self, request, pk, format=None, renderer_context=None):
    """
    returns an XML of a jobmst listing
    """
    template_vars['jobmst'] = (queryset1, [pk])
    template_vars['jobdtl'] = (queryset2, [pk]) 
    template_vars['jobdep'] = (queryset3, [pk])

    t = loader.get_template('TidalAPI/templates/xml_template.xml')
    c = Context(template_vars)

    return HttpResponse(t.render(c), mimetype="text/xml")
```

When I try to hit my url at `http://localhost:8080/TidalDEV/10081/` I get invalid syntax. What is the problem here?

Essentially I need the view to populate a template XML file I built.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing a comma after your index view in TidalDEV/urls.py

Comment: It happens to everyone. Also, you might find the built in `render` shortcut useful - it's rare that you need to use a template's `render` method directly. There's nothing wrong with doing that if you like, but you can shorten the code.

Comment: I'm trying to create a custom xml to match a legacy application and as such I need to load into a template :(  I'm getting a new error now I'll post up a new question.

Comment: It's not that there's anything wrong with using a template to produce XML, it's just that there are simpler ways to express the code chain of "render this template with this context and put the results in this response object". If I happen to see your new question I'll take a look, though of course I can't promise anything.

Comment: I've got it!  Ya I have my "final state" which involves using django-rest-framework and it's much easier and less coding to get the same XML but due to the custom nature of this legacy app there's some things I just haven't been able to do easier.